# Regex for matching complete substring

Tags: regex

Sorry for the dummy question but I'm a regular expressions newbie.

I want these matches:

```
MATCH!     http://www.google.com/search?q=...
NO MATCH   http://www.googledummy.com/search?q=...
MATCH!     http://www.google.it/search?q=...
NO MATCH!  http://www.google.it/
NO MATCH!  http://www.google.it/foobar 
MATCH!     google.it/search?q=...    
MATCH!     google.xxxxx/search?q=...
```

Should my regex be something like this?

```
google.[*$]/search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:[^.\s]+\.)*google(\.\w+){1,2}/search\?q=
```

This regex allows:

- `^` - match from the start - do not allow partial matching of the domain.
- `(?:https?://)?` - http or https protocol.
- `(?:[^.]+\.)*` - sub domains, but not other characters: `hello.google.com` is OK.
- google

Does not allow:

- `http://notgoogle.com/search?q=`
- `http://example.com?google.com/search?q=`

Problems:

- `(\.\w+){1,2}` - allows google.co.il, but also google.hackers.com. It's problematic unless you want to white list all two-word tlds.
- the `q` query parameter may not be the first one (though, maybe that is one of the requirements).
- `\w` may not fit all characters that are valid in top level domains (though google is not likely to buy `google.קום`)

Example: http://rubular.com/r/Avd5RFs3oH

Conclusion - If at all applicable, use a URL parser `:)`

Answer (score 0):

from what you wrote I would say

```
google\.[a-z]+\/search
```

whether you should use `\/` or just `/`  before `search` depends on the language you are using.

As  SeRPRo this does not work for google.co.uk, to make it working with it you can use:

```
google\.[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z])?\/search
```

(is there any country that requires a third level?)

Comment: Admittedly that wasn't among the examples the gave so maybe it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
google\.[a-zA-Z\.]+/(search\W.+)
```

[Example](http://xrg.es/?1792273737)

Comment: This will also allow arbitrary characters like &*^$% in domain name

Comment: Fair enough, though it's a weird case, I'll edit to match only letters an dots.

Comment: And they asked only for a regex, not how you'd write and escape a regex in some particular language, so I guess the delimiters re unnecessary unless you're dealing with PHP or Perl ...

Answer (score 0):

You might want the following:

`google\.[a-zA-Z.]+/search`

Both other answers should work fine until you meet a second-level google site like `google.com.ua`

Comment: @Joey: Damn nasty habit to escape everything. Corrected.